# Login process always failing in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. It was working fine when suddenly I could no longer sign in users.

I checked the connection string, it works fine. I tried rewriting the sign in code without any luck. I've tried both Local IIS and IIS Express. I tried recreating the project. No matter what I've tried the sign in manager always returns Failure.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I completely rewrote the entire login/registration process. I have another site with the same problem now. Not sure what's going on. Might be a dependxy DLL corruption issue.

Comment: Have you checked that it is not to do with their email not being validated?

Comment: I thought it might be that. It doesn't seem to be the issue. I'm dealing with a black box though so it's hard to be 100% sure. I tried recreating the user database to see if there was a data issue. Seems fine.

Comment: may be it has an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36384658)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Possibly the issue is that the above function requires `username` in 1st param but you are providing `email`.

Comment: My ```username``` and ```email``` are the same so that wasn't the problem. The code was working fine in Edge but not Firefox. Yesterday I enabled HTTPS and the code started working in all browsers.